# Cannot retrieve this JSON datas

Tags: php, arrays, json

I tried retrieving the word "John" for example using this way.

**Code**

```
$decoded = json_decode('$thejson');  
$myvar =  $decoded->name;
echo $myvar;
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "50",
    "Job": "Developer"
  }
]
```

I think the first squarre brackets are the thing blocking me here
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work this way:

```
$myvar =  $decoded[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($thejson,TRUE);  
$myvar =  $decoded[0]['name'];
```

[image]

[image]